# Simplest way to convert amazon-linux instance from PV to HVM

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualization

I tried to shift m3.medium instance from Sydney to Mumbai using following steps.

> 1. Created AMI in Sydney.
> 2. Copied that AMI to Mumbai
> 3. Tried to launch EC2 instance using that AMI.

The console shows message

> "No matching instance type found"

.

Then I Googled a little bit and found that my current instance is Paravirtual (PV) and I should convert it to Hardware-assisted Virtual Machine (HVM).

I found following threads

- [AWS Forum Thread 1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=678580)
- [AWS Forum Thread 2](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=553638)
- [Serverfault Thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/439976/create-an-aws-hvm-linux-ami-from-an-existing-paravirtual-linux-ami)

However the solutions provided there are bit complicated for me being a newbie in AWS.

Is there a simplest way to achieve this using AWS Web Console?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is not.

Comment: I used **@Andy999X's** solution posted [**here**](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=558423&#558423)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way out -

1. In sydney, create a snapshot of the instance
2. Using the snapshot, create a new AMI in HVM mode(use)

ec2-register -n hvmami -s snap-08b00961a035ec238 --virtualization-type hvm

3. Copy this AMI to mumbai
4. Create a new instance in HVM mode.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, however I have used the solution which I had mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Had a similar issue trying to launch an EC2 from a PV AMI and this worked liked a charm